# Datetime, Timedelta and separate lineplot, plot area

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

My df has index with time datetime64 and my columns are timedelta and float64. Below 3 example rows of my df.

```
                          CTIL            downtime     ratio                           
quater          

2015-04-01  4859 days 01:46:00  1699 days 17:20:00  0.349804
2015-07-01  4553 days 14:16:00  1862 days 03:27:00  0.408939
2015-10-01  5502 days 21:18:00  2442 days 20:15:00  0.443920
```

I would like to plot in on one chart. CTIL and downtime should be area plots and ratio should be a line chart.

Current I have 2 separate plots:

```
df_quater[['CTIL', 'downtime']].plot()
```

[image]

```
df_quater['ratio'].plot()
```

[image]

Question 1:
How can I plot area plot when type of x is different than y.
I try this:

> df_quater[['CTIL', 'downtime']].plot(kind='area')

It generate error

> TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc greater_equal input (...) with casting rule 'same_kind'

Question 2:
Can my labels on y be in deltatime format? Current plot has numbers.

Qustion 3:
Can I connect this 2 plot into one? Label for CTIL and downright.time should be on left and label for ratio should be on